# How to store a cookie value in jquery while clicking the checkbox (Multiples value are possible)

Tags: jquery, cookies

Let us consider i am having a text box where i can enter user names separated by commas.

**In Detail:**

1. I am having a text box and a search_button nearby.
2. When i click on the search box list of users will be displayed there in a popup with a check box nearby
3. When the user the clicks the check box and clicks submit the corresponding users name will be displayed on the text box.
4. My problem is: **I need to store every value of the check box which i clicked and to store it in cookie using jquery. ***

   ```
    ** There is the possible of storing multiple values separated by commas. **
    ** There should not be duplicates. **
   ```

Any help will be thankful and grateful....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @@Devjosh: thanks for the comment. But i am in need to store values in cookie.. That plays a major role here... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do that with this plugin cookie (See below),
with that you can do something like:

```
var App = {
count:0,

clickedCheckbox:function(e)
{
    $.cookie('userCheckValue_'+this.count, e.target.value);
    this.count++;
}
```

}

And implement more function for the specific key, check if already exists some value
etc ...

```
jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
    options = options || {};
    if (value === null) {
        value = '';
        options.expires = -1;
    }
    var expires = '';
    if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
        var date;
        if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
            date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        } else {
            date = options.expires;
        }
        expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
    }
    // CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
    // in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
    // in the packed version for some reason...
    var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
    var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
    var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
    document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
} else { // only name given, get cookie
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

};